# Python: unexplainable case in variable copying

Tags: python, function, variables, copying, shadowing

Given the following program, I want the variable `bar` to keep the same.

```
def foo(bar):
    bar2 = bar[:]
    chg = []
    for p in range(4):
        for q in range(3):
            chg.append([p,q])
    for [x,y] in chg:
        bar2[x][y] = "xx"
    return bar2

def printGrid(grid):
    for row in grid:
        print " ".join(row)    
    print

bar = [[str(i) + str(j) for i in range(5)] for j in range(6)]
printGrid(bar)
printGrid(foo(bar))
printGrid(bar)
```

However, this is the output:

```
00 10 20 30 40
01 11 21 31 41
02 12 22 32 42
03 13 23 33 43
04 14 24 34 44
05 15 25 35 45

xx xx xx 30 40
xx xx xx 31 41
xx xx xx 32 42
xx xx xx 33 43
04 14 24 34 44
05 15 25 35 45

xx xx xx 30 40
xx xx xx 31 41
xx xx xx 32 42
xx xx xx 33 43
04 14 24 34 44
05 15 25 35 45
```

I don't understand. The first 2 grids are as expected, but when did `bar` change? How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: your grid is 2d. it is array of arrays. when you `[:]` you copy the first level only, therefore bar2[x] is the same object as bar[x]

Comment: try using `bar2 = copy.deepcopy(bar)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bar` is a list of pointers. You are copying those pointers with `bar2 = bar[:]`. But, unless you change those pointers, they still point to the same lists, so `bar[x][y]` and `bar2[x][y]` refer to the same data. Try using

```
bar2 = copy.deepcopy(bar)
```

instead of

```
bar2 = bar[:]
```

You'll need to `import copy`